# Azure api management Publisher portal To power Bi?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-api-management, powerbi-embedded

i'm wondering if there is any way to export the Publisher portal in azure api management to a power bi dashboard?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIM does have a REST API that supports ODATA queries. This should be compatible with PowerBI. You can enable REST API in Security section in APIM publisher portal.

Since you're interested in reporting data you could start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/reports